# Not Allowing SQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I want to select some `id` from a table based on a condition, and update them.

```
 UPDATE user_feed
    SET `status` = 'DELETED'
    WHERE
        id IN (
            SELECT
                feed.id
            FROM
                user_activity act
            JOIN user_feed feed ON act.id = feed.activity_id
            WHERE
                act.uid = 16
            AND feed. STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
        )
```

Showing this error

> [SQL]UPDATE user_feed set `status`='DELETED' Where id IN  (select
>   feed.id from user_activity act join user_feed feed on act.id =
>   feed.activity_id where act.uid = 16 and feed.status = 'ACTIVE')
>
> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'user_feed' for update in
>   FROM clause

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps `update user_feed uf
join  user_activity ua on ua.id = uf.activity_id
set uf.status = 'DELETED'
where 
ua.uid = 16 and uf.status = 'ACTIVE'`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `join` in the `update` statement.  I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE user_feed f join
       user_activity a
       on a.id = f.activity_id and a.uid = 16 
    set f.`status` = 'DELETED'
    Where f.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

Comment: Unknown column 'f.status' in 'field list' having this error

Comment: According to your question, `user_feed` has a column called `status`.